# SAS date difference

Tags: sas

what is wrong in below code

```
%let a='2017-01-01';
%let b='2017-12-01';


%let days = %sysfunc(intck(month,"&a"d,"&b"d));
%put days;
```

Below is the error

```
ERROR: Argument 2 to function INTCK referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
ERROR: Argument 3 to function INTCK referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
ERROR: Invalid arguments detected in %SYSCALL, %SYSFUNC, or %QSYSFUNC argument list.  Execution of %SYSCALL statement or %SYSFUNC 
    or %QSYSFUNC function reference is terminated.
67         %put days;
days
```

Comment: What is the larger question? We cannot know what is wrong if you don't tell what you are trying to do. Also why are A and B defined in that format?

Comment: You can not quote a macro variable using double quotes, when referring inside another macro var. You can use `%superq`, `%bquote`, `%quote`, `%str`, etc. You macro variable could be `%let days = %sysfunc(intck(month,&a.d,&b.d));` or `%let days = %sysfunc(intck(month,%superq(a)d,%superq(a)d));`. Try them once!

Comment: Actually, you would have to change them to date from the macro string first. so, `%let days = %sysfunc(intck(month,%sysfunc(inputn(&a,yymmddd10.),%sysfunc(inputn(&a,yymmddd10.)));` now, the function should evaluate as dates.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. Your dates are not SAS date literals. SAS date literals take the format of `'DDMMMYYYY'd` or `'DDMMMYY'd` For example, `01JAN2018'd`, or `01JAN18'd`.
2. You have put quotes around your macro variables that declare the dates, and put double-quotes around them a second time when calling `intck.`
3. An `&` needs to prefix `days`.

The below code addresses these problems:

```
%let a=01JAN2017;
%let b=01DEC2017;


%let months = %sysfunc(intck(month,"&a"d,"&b"d));
%put &months;
```

Because you are calculating the number of months between January 2017 and December 2017, I renamed your macro variable to `months`.

Comment: what if dates are coming from teradata then how do we find the difference

Comment: If they already **came** from Teradata then they are now SAS dates so nothing needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this in explicit SQL pass through. for doing that you have to something like this and you can use Teradata specific functions.

```
/* define  date as Teradata Understands*/
     %let a= '2017-01-01';
    %let b= '2017-12-01';

 /* use either of solutions and I do not have Teradata handy, so I did
 not   explicitly checked this */

SELECT  CAST(&b AS DATE) - CAST(&a AS DATE) MONTH(4);

select floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(date &b - date &a));
```